# Jython with both Python and Java in Pydev

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to set up a development enviroment for a Jython project, in particular with PyDev in Eclipse. The enviroment is trying to emulate a jython custom call, which has the following configuration file

```
java.mainclass=org/python/util/jython
java.classpath=C:\Program Files\Jython\jython.jar
java.classpath=C:\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\NSH\br
java.classpath=C:\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\NSH\br\stdlib
java.classpath=C:\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\NSH\br\deployments
java.classpath=<default>
jvm.arg=-Xmx1024M
jvm.arg=-Dblx.cmrootdir=C:\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\NSH\br
jvm.arg=-Dpython.home=C:\Program Files\Jython
jvm.arg=-Dcom.bladelogic.cli.xmldir=C:\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\NSH\br\xml\cli
```

with PyDev it is easy to emulate with four last options via VM arguments in Run Configuration. But how can I force the classpath to be the one in the configuration file in thar particular order?

THanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked on another forum, answer was given, with a full video demo.

Tricks included avoiding spaces in path:
- BladeLogic installation is in c:\BMC\BladeLogic in order to keep the paths short.
- Jython install is in C:\jython - again, to keep the paths short
- Eclipse workspace is in H:\Development - for the same reason.

All details (including video) on https://communities.bmc.com/message/401377#401377

Comment: Indeed, forgot about posting that here